# What are the correct names of the parking spaces for turn-around?

Tags: commercial-aviation, airport

A plane can be parked at the terminal and the passengers can board through a jet bridge. Also it can be parked somewhere else, far away from the terminal and the passengers would need to take the bus to get there.

What is the correct name of those parking spaces?[image]
[image]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

They are referred to as **aircraft stands**.

ICAO Definition:

> *Aircraft stand.*
>   A designated area on an apron intended to be used for parking an aircraft.

Stands at the terminal building are commonly referred to as gates, while stands further away may be referred to as remote stands or remote gates. The *aircraft stand* term covers both types.