# Is "passenger loading bridge" a synonym to "contact stand"?

Tags: terminology, airport-design, boarding

In a master plan of an international airport, which is already approved by the client, I face some confusion between the terminology of the PLB and the contact stand.

Sometimes they're mentioned just as the same component, not like other locations. I assumed a sort of a conflict in the master plan but I'd like to confirm this please.

Is there any  benchmark like ICAO or IATA that defines such components, e.g., the gate, rotunda, PLB, contact stand, etc.?

Comment: Have you consideder asking the client for clarification?

Comment: I'm working within Client's PMC firm who joined the project recently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ICAO Annex 14, which deals with aerodrome design (not really terminals) uses the terms PLB and aerobridge.

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jet_bridge) lists many names for it, with the official being PBB (Passenger Boarding Bridge). The names listed are jet bridge, jetway ®, gangway, aerobridge/airbridge, air jetty, portal, and skybridge.

Official FAA documents use the term PBB. ([Example](https://www.faa.gov/airports/resources/advisory_circulars/index.cfm/go/document.information/documentID/1029771).)

*Contact stand* most probably is used to distinguish it from a *[remote stand](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/30638/what-are-the-correct-names-of-the-parking-spaces-for-turn-around),* it's not very popular according to Google. Rotunda or pivot describes that a PBB pivots, or perhaps the pivoting / telescoping part.

To answer the main question, yes they all mean the same thing, with PBB being an official name.

Comment: In Germany they are colloquially called _finger_. I always thought that was the international term and was surprised that this is not the case. (German _Finger_ == English _finger_, the ten grabbing devices attached to a human hand.)

Comment: @PerlDuck: "*the ten grabbing devices attached to a human hand*": Some people have only five :-)

Comment: @mins Some people say the thumbs don't count, which then gives only four. :-) I just wanted to make clear that _finger_ in German is nothing else than in English (unlike e.g. _chef_ which exists in German as well but has nothing to do with cooking).

Comment: @PerlDuck: Just kidding. Read [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brigade_de_cuisine) to see the extent the kitchen lingo comes from French. The best oddity to me is *[maître d'](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ma%C3%AEtre_d%27h%C3%B4tel)* (litteraly "master of"). I'm sure there is the same number of oddities in every language though.